# pyramid - how to configure multiple forbidden view depend on resource factory?

Tags: authentication, pyramid

I have a pyramid projects, with 2 parts:

- `/_hq/` requires authentication by a login page
- `/_rest/` requires RESTful authentication (through HTTP Basic/Digest Authentication)

So, I add the route with 2 main resource factories: *HQFactory* and *RESTFactory*. I've built a authentication policy switcher to switch AuthenticationPolicy per resource. It worked.

I use ACLAuthorizationPolicy too.

For each request, I want to return a *login page* or *401 HTTP Status* depends on what resource factory is being accessed.

My problem is I can do *@forbidden_view_config* for only one view. How can I specify for bidden view per resource factory or another solution for my problems?

Thank you

### Solved - Solution

**The simplest way is Michael Merickel's answer (you can see it below)**. There's another way here:

*Deprecated*

I solved my problem by using custom_predicates arg from view_config. This is it.

I created a function as a custom predicate:

```
def resource_factory_predicate(factory):
    def check_factory(context, request):
        return isinstance(request.context, factory)
return check_factory
```

Then, here's my views.py

```
# views.py
@forbidden_view_config(
custom_predicates=(resource_factory_predicate(RootFactory),))
def login_required(request):
    userid = authenticated_userid(request)

    if userid is not None:
        return HTTPForbidden("You're not authorized for this action")

    # redirect to login page


@forbidden_view_config(renderer='json',
    custom_predicates=(resource_factory_predicate(RESTfulFactory),))
def http_403_unauthenticated(request):
    request.response.status = 403
    return {
        'status': 0,
        'message': 'Forbidden',
    }
```

Comment: *Why* can you only do `@forbidden_view_config` for only one view? Pyramid doesn't put that restriction on it. Use predicates to register *two* such views.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about passing context to @forbiden_view_config, but it has restriction as my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you cannot dispatch an exception view based on the context (the exception is used as the context) it is possible to cheat and use the `containment` option which requires that the specified type is in the [`lineage`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#predicate-arguments) of the actual context. This means it will also match if any context below it raises the exception, affecting an entire subtree of your traversal hierarchy.

```
@forbidden_view_config(containment=MyRootA)
def root_a_forbidden(exc, request):
    # note that the actual context is available on request.context
    pass

@forbidden_view_config(containment=MyRootB)
def root_b_forbidden(exc, request):
    pass
```

Comment: Wow, thanks very much. This solution is simpler, easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The forbidden view is a view like any other, really; see the [`@forbidden_view_config()` decorator documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/view.html#pyramid.view.forbidden_view_config):

> An analogue of `pyramid.view.view_config` which registers a *forbidden view*.
>
> The `forbidden_view_config` constructor accepts most of the same arguments as the constructor of `pyramid.view.view_config`. It can be used in the same places, and behaves in largely the same way, except it always registers a forbidden exception view instead of a ‘normal’ view.

This means it accepts the same predicates as `pyramid.view.view_config()` does; the decorator basically calls [`add_forbidden_view()`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_forbidden_view), which means its arguments can be used in the decorator; the documentation for that method explicitly excludes `context`, but a route name *is* an option:

```
@forbidden_view_config(route_name='hq'):
def forbidden_for_hq(request):
    # ...

@forbidden_view_config(route_name='rest'):
def forbidden_for_rest(request):
    # ...
```

If there are too many routes to map to, consider using a [custom predicate](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#view-and-route-predicates). You already have custom authentication policy switcher; all you need to do is add a custom predicate that'll detect which policy is being used.

Comment: I tried your solution but context argument can not be passed to forbidden_view_config. It will raise a ConfigurationError exception
'context may not be used as an argument to add_forbidden_view'

Comment: Blergh, that's a documentation fail then. What predicates do you use to select your context in the first place? Perhaps you can use the route as a predicate instead?

Comment: I have many routes for both HQ and REST, if I use route instead of context, I will have to specify many routes, and update the forbidden decorator whenever I add a new route, that's too hard.

Comment: @Tarzan: Ah, located better documentation (`add_forbidden_view` indeed explicitly excludes `context`), but a `route_name` should suffice here, right?

Comment: Thank you, route name make me so hard. I found a arg name 'custom_predicate'. Now I'm googling about it. As your experiences, can I solve my problem?

Comment: Sure; you already have custom authentication policy switcher; all you need to do is add a custom predicate that'll detect which policy is being used.

Comment: Thank you, I've solved that. Please update your answer so I can choose it as answer for other members who get this problem.

Comment: @Tarzan: It was already there in the answer, just using different wording. I've updated it to use the wording from my comment instead.